# Change the email placeholder in cloudfoundry uaa

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I've managed to install and configure a Cloudfoundry UAA app in my network. I'd like to change the **Email** placeholder text to say **Username**. Is there a way to do this through the uaa.yml file?

Comment: I believe you can set something like `login: {prompt: {username: {text: Username}}}` in your `login.yml` file.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work. I added the login.yml right next to my uaa.yml file in the UAA_CONFIG_PATH folder with the suggested text and it's still prompting for Email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that your login.yml has the the following setting

`login:
  prompt:
    username:
     text: Employee ID`

Comment: It worked! Thanks... Had to do it on the actual file though, I was hoping I could do it as with the uaa.yml file inside an external config folder. But glad it works... Thanks again!